# How to make a callback function to subscribe to a non string topic?

Tags: ros, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I've followed succesfully all basic tutorials. Then I moved to stage to work on a robot simulation. I also installed the joystick_drivers stack to use a joystick to move my virtual robot in stage. Everything is working properly (I can see the messages, topics, node graph, etc).

Right now, I tried to modify the simple subscriber 'listener' of the basic tutorials to read the information of my joystick. The problem is that the example is made for a string message.

The callback function in the tutorial is something like this:
void chatterCallback(const std_msgs::String::ConstPtr& msg){
ROS_INFO("I heard: [%s]", msg->data.c_str());
}

But in the joy topic I am reading Joy messages:
float32[] axes
int32[] buttons

How do I manage this 'complex' messages in a correct callback function?

Thnx alot for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12002/how-to-make-a-callback-function-to-subscribe-to-a-non-string-topic?/) by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on ROS Answers with karma: 107 on 2011-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Add the [sensor_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/sensor_msgs) package to your dependencies in your `manifest.xml` with `<depend package="sensor_msgs"/>`, then include the appropriate C++ message header file with `#include <sensor_msgs/Joy.h>`, and change the callback to

```
void myCallback (const sensor_msgs::Joy::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < msg->axes.size(); ++i) {
    ROS_INFO("Axis %d is now at position %f", i, msg->axes[i]);
  }
}
```

---

Originally posted by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) with karma: 1951 on 2011-11-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcobecerrap](https://answers.ros.org/users/1277/marcobecerrap/) on 2011-11-21**:
Hi Röhling, thank you very much for your help!!! Your answer was the explanation that I needed. Now everything is working  just perfect!!! Thanks alot!